# Java Processbuilder returns 255

Tags: java, c++, command-line

I want to run C++ program exe with text input and output but somehow processbuilder returns 255 and does not print results to output txt.

```
    public static void runCommandPrompt(String[] cmds)  {
    ProcessBuilder compileProcessBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(cmds);
    Process compileProcess = null;
    try {
        compileProcess = compileProcessBuilder.start();
        int exitValue = compileProcess.waitFor();
        System.out.println(exitValue);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



public static void main(String[] args){
    String[] evaluateCommands = { "cmd", 
               "/c",
               "cd C:\\TestPath & select.exe <C:\\input.txt >C:\\output.txt" };
    runCommandPrompt(evaluateCommands);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to redirect all output of the child process to the main process. I believe you will see the error reason.

```
ProcessBuilder compileProcessBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(cmds);

// redirect all IO separately
compileProcessBuilder.redirectInput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
compileProcessBuilder.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
compileProcessBuilder.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);

// or use a convenient call for all at once (thanks VGR to mention it)
compileProcessBuilder.inheritIO();

Process compileProcess = compileProcessBuilder.start();
```

**update**

What do the process return if you start them manually? Maybe they really return those exit codes.

**run.cmd**

```
select.exe <C:\input.txt >C:\output.txt
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
```

Comment: You can also do this with one method call:  compileProcessBuilder.[inheritIO()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO--)

Comment: @VGR You're right. I only wanted to show the verbose version. I put your comment into the answer. It's a good addition.

Comment: Thanks your helping. But I have another problem. I am TA of a C++ lecture. So try to compile and test results automatically. So I decided to write Java program. Program gets homeworks folder. Then foreach student folder, it calls cl compiler and creates an exe. After that program tries for testcase but there is a problem. Program runs exe in for loop foreach student but some processes return correct but some processes fails and returns 255 or -1073741819. I do not understand why fails same commands for some exes and does not fail others. When I used your solution, problem still exists

Comment: @setr My answer was not intended to be a solution. Rather it should allow you to see the output of the child process (if there is any).